# Collapsing SSRS matrix rows and columns

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008-r2

How would I combine the matrix below so that the race lines appear once with column totals to the right?

[image]

New image showing grouping:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just need to **Group** your **Row** by **Race**.

In the Design view, the row probably has the three lines indicating that it's detail instead of grouped (which have the parenthesis-looking line).

Right click on your row with **Race -> Row Group -> Group Properties** and Add a new grouping by your **Race** field.

[image]

Make sure your **Total** and **17P** cells use a **SUM** - if they were a detail row they might just be the single value.

Comment: Hannover First - thanks, but it's already in a row group as a matrix, not table and using sum.  I think it has something to do with the two columns being needed a total and a 17p?

Comment: The Total and 17P columns shouldn't be an issue since they are in the **Column Grouping**. Is there another Group field in the **Row Grouping**? If you are grouping just by Race, are you sure that some of your Race fields don't have an extra space at the end?